# Laptop Built-in Fingerprint Logon to Domain Joined Computer

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2, netlogon, fingerprint-reader

Is this possible:

I have a Windows Server 2012 R2 running Active Directory. I have installed Windows Biometric Framework and made the changes in Group Policy to allow Fingerprint Signon

The Laptop is domain-joined with a built-in fingerprint scanner running Windows 10 on the Latest Update.

How to setup so that users can sign into the domain using their Fingerprint Readers on the laptops?

Test : Setting up Fingerprint Signon only allocates it to the local profile of the device.